# Is Amazon Kinesis Firehose necessary to scale?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

My goal is to store data received through an SNS subscription in Amazon Redshift. I have successfully managed to store the data using a lambda function, simply through creating a Redshift connection and calling a prepared insert statement. While the lambda does reuse the connection, I use connection pooling to ensure that I don't lose the connection and end up spending 5-10 seconds reconnecting.

This process has worked perfectly well for smaller scale tests, and I don't come close to using all of my lambda concurrency. But, I'm afraid that this flow may cause problems when I begin to subscribe to a considerably more active SNS (up to 100 records/sec).

While I know the aws documentation and many online forums recommend firehose because of its scalability, one of my number one priorities is cost reduction, and firehose seems extremely costly (the price of firehose + cost of intermediate s3 bucket). Does anyone have any experience with trying to bypass firehose by programmatically storing in Redshift/other databases?

Comment: how do you add data using lambda (using s3 and copy or as inserts)?

Comment: @JonScott I use inserts- that way I don't need an intermediary s3

Comment: That will not scale.. you need to convert to using s3 and copy (or firehose)

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it would not scale?

Comment: Redshift is not a transaction DB, it is not designed for large number of record by record inserts they are orders of magnitude slower than the correct approach. There is plenty of documentation and help here if you search. and - if you dont believe then just try it.

Comment: Update: I tried the insert setup with 140 records/sec- @JonScott when you're right, you're right. All the inserts just racked up, and my lambdas became extremely slow. Currently working on a fix to use s3 and then batch copy. One issue I ran into was concurrent reads/writes to s3, so I'm implementing an SQS to fix that. I'm still devoted to not using firehouse :D

Comment: Sounds like a good plan - that will work. what is your objection to firehose?

Comment: The reason I don't like firehose is because when calculating the price per GB of data ingested, aws rounds up each record to the nearest 5 KB. And each of my records is 600 B

Comment: Ah right - short records. fair enough i think at your volume of 100 recs per second for 24/7/365 it would cost you $37 per month approx.

Comment: While firehose seemed like the wrong product for my use case, after looking into the price of SQS I've decided to go with firehose, since SQS+S3 would be 3x more expensive than firehose+S3.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simplify your architecture now that SNS has added native support for message archiving and analytics via Kinesis Data Firehose subscriptions. In your case, you’d simply configure Redshift as the destination of your Firehose delivery stream, then subscribe this stream directly to your SNS topic.

More info:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/01/amazon-sns-adds-support-for-message-archiving-and-analytics-via-kineses-data-firehose-subscriptions/